# GAE Logout connection to session

Tags: google-app-engine

When I create a logout link for the user to logout of my GAE application, and the user logs out, do I have to manually kill their session,  or is the session destroyed when they logout?

Answer (score 1):

Logout has no impact on a session. There may be all sorts of other useful information in a session that an app may need regardless of whether a user is logged in using App Engine's User Service or not.

After a user logs out, this is up to you whether to kill the entire session or just remove an authentication flag/object from the session. It all depends on what you use a session for.